# ¿Como lograr que un botón se desplaza con un MouseListener?

Tags: java, eventos, jframe, interfaz-gráfica

Cuento con un panel el cual contiene un botón lo que quiero logra hacer es que cuando el cursor del mouse se acerque a dicho botón este se mueva de posición para que al usuario le sea imposible tocarlo y una vez que el cursor del mouse sale del panel el botón regrese a su posición inicial ya logro mover el botón de posiciones a posiciones aleatorias el problema es que cuando el cursor entra al panel el botón se mueve inmediatamente aunque el cursor no se encuentre cercas de el como corrijo esto. Dejo el código que llevo al momento:

```
public class Crazy_butt {

//Interfaz grafica de usuario

    private JFrame ventana;
    private JPanel panelC;
    private JButton bot1;
    private int x,y;
    Random alea;
// Consrructor que inicializa los componentes

    public Crazy_butt() {

        ventana = new JFrame();
        panelC = new JPanel();
        bot1 = new JButton();
        alea = new Random();
        this.atributos();
        this.armado();
        this.ecuchas();
        this.lanazar_IGU();
    }

    // Atributos de los componentes
    public void atributos() {
        ventana.setSize(500, 500);
        ventana.setResizable(true);
        panelC.setLayout(null);
        bot1.setText("tocame");
        bot1.setBounds(190, 190, 100, 40);
    }

    public void armado() {

        ventana.add(panelC);
        panelC.add(bot1);

    }

    // Asignar los escuchas
    public void ecuchas() {
        Escucha_Raton esc = new Escucha_Raton();
        panelC.addMouseListener(esc);
//        bot1.addActionListener(esc);
    }

    public void lanazar_IGU() {
        ventana.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ventana.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        ventana.setVisible(true);
    }

    class Escucha_Raton implements MouseListener {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
               x = alea.nextInt(400);
               y= alea.nextInt(400);
               bot1.setBounds(x,y,100,40);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            bot1.setBounds(190,190,100,40);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema esta en que estas agregando el Listener al Panel y no al ratón; pero también el Listener esta mal para agregarlo al boton porque este se descontrolara.

Veamos porque, en el mouse entered dice que cuando el ratón entre en el botón que salga a una posición (x,y) aleatoria con lo cual el botón saldrá de la posición del ratón y activara el evento mouse exited

```
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    x = alea.nextInt(400);
    y= alea.nextInt(400);
    bot1.setBounds(x,y,100,40);
}
```

y en el evento mouse exited dice, devuelve al botón a su posición original con lo cual el botón saldrá y entrara del ratón tan rápido como tu pc lo permita.

Ahora al agregar el Listener al Panel parece que funciona; la primer vez que entra el ratón al panel el mouse entered se activa y el botón se mueve; pero al tocar al botón el mouse exited del panel se activa y el ratón vuelve a su posición original pero al volver a su posición original el mouse entered del panel se vuelve a activar; seria una solución a medias.

Entonces como quieres que cuando el ratón salga del panel el botón vuelva a su posición inicial, crea un MouseListener para el panel y en el evento mouse exited pon:

```
bot1.setBounds(190,190,100,40);
```

y en el Listener del boton solo pon el mouse entered, aca el codigo corregido:

```
public class Crazy_butt {

//Interfaz grafica de usuario

private JFrame ventana;
private JPanel panelC;
private JButton bot1;
private int x,y;
private Random alea;

public static final int oposx = 190;
public static final int oposy = 190;    
public static final int tamx  = 100;
public static final int tamy  = 40;

// Consrructor que inicializa los componentes

public Crazy_butt() {
    ventana = new JFrame();
    panelC = new JPanel();
    bot1 = new JButton();
    alea = new Random();
    this.atributos();
    this.armado();
    this.ecuchas();
    this.lanazar_IGU();
}

// Atributos de los componentes

public void atributos() {
    ventana.setSize(500, 500);
    ventana.setResizable(true);
    panelC.setLayout(null);
    bot1.setText("tocame");
    bot1.setBounds(oposx, oposy, tamx, tamy);
}

public void armado() {
    ventana.add(panelC);
    panelC.add(bot1);
}

// Asignar los escuchas

public void ecuchas() {
    BotonEscucha_Raton esc_b = new BotonEscucha_Raton();
    PanelEscucha_Raton esc_p = new PanelEscucha_Raton();
    panelC.addMouseListener(esc_p);
    bot1.addMouseListener(esc_b);
}

public void lanazar_IGU() {
    ventana.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    ventana.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    ventana.setVisible(true);
}

private class BotonEscucha_Raton implements MouseListener {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)  { }
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)  { }
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) { }
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        x = alea.nextInt(400);
        y = alea.nextInt(400);
        bot1.setBounds(x,y,tamx,tamy);
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) { }
}

private class PanelEscucha_Raton implements MouseListener {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)  { }
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)  { }
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) { }
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)  { }
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        bot1.setBounds(oposx,oposy,tamx,tamy);
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new Crazy_butt();
        }
    });
}
}
```

pero hay raras veces que el cursor esta sobre el botón y este no se mueve, no se a que se debe esto para solucionarlo cambie el botón escucha para que implemente de MouseMotionListener y cambie solo el metodo mouse moved asi:

```
    private class BotonEscucha_Raton implements MouseMotionListener {
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) { }
        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            Rectangle r;
            Point p;
            //Comporbamos que la nueva posicion no este dentro del mouse
            do{
                x = alea.nextInt(400);
                y = alea.nextInt(400);
                r = new Rectangle(x,y,tamx,tamy);
            }while(r.contains(p));
            bot1.setBounds(x,y,tamx,tamy);
        }
    }
```

y al agregarlo al boton:

```
public void ecuchas() {
    BotonEscucha_Raton esc_b = new BotonEscucha_Raton();
    PanelEscucha_Raton esc_p = new PanelEscucha_Raton();
    panelC.addMouseListener(esc_p);
    bot1.addMouseMotionListener(esc_b);
}
```

Comment: Muy buena respuesta Tony Angello me ayudo mucho

Comment: Solo una cuestión mas agregue otro botón mas el problema que al ejecutar el programa hay ocasiones en que los dos botones se ponen uno encima de otro como lo soluciono dejo el pedazo de código donde agrego el otro boton: public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            x = alea.nextInt(380);
            y = alea.nextInt(410);
            x2 = alea.nextInt(380);
            y2 = alea.nextInt(410);
            
            bot1.setBounds(x, y, 100, 40);
            bot2.setBounds(x2,y2,100,40);
        }